# select all the employees whose date of birth falls end of month

Tags: sql, oracle

Let us say I have a table called `Employee` in Oracle with following structure.

```
EMPLOYEE:
  NAME VARCHAR2(60)
  DOB  TIMESTAMP
  SAL  NUMBER
```

I want a query that selects all the employees whose DOB falls on last day of month.

i.e. (1/31, 2/28 or 2/29 based on year, 3/31 ....)

Comment: Any specific reason for tagging this question for "mysql"? Seems like you are using Orcale.

Comment: Any db will work general idea.

Comment: There is no general idea among different DBMS vendors when it comes to string and date/time functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd approach this would be to add a day to it then see if the day of the month is the 1st.

I don't know Oracle specifically, but since you said general idea in MSSQL I'd do `datepart(d, dateadd(day, 1, DOB)) = 1`

Answer (score 6):

In oracle `Last_day()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DOB=Last_day(DOB)
```

Comment: this assumes that DOB always has its time component = 12am

Comment: I didn't say your answer was wrong. I'm just pointing out it makes an assumption. If the data always has the time component = 12am, your answer will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL,

```
SELECT * FROM table 
Where Datediff(dd,DOB,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DOB)+1,0)))=0
```